# REST API - trying to extract a value from JSON and appending it to a DELETE operation

Tags: api, curl

I want to run a CURL command to query a REST API.

After running the command:

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://website.com/api/v2/data/apps/conf' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Api-Token: TOKEN'
```

I am getting the JSON response that looks like

```
   "data" : {
      "conf" : [
         {
            "app_id" : 2,
            "app_name" : "Test App" : false,
            "host" : "10.10.10.10",
            "app_protocol" : "http",
            "protocols" : [
               {
                  "created_at" : "2022-06-06T11:25:40.444Z",
                  "id" : 103,
                  "port" : "22",
                  "service_id" : 2,
                  "transport" : "tcp",
                  "updated_at" : "2022-06-06T11:25:40.444Z"
               }
            ],
            "reachability" : null,
            "assignments" : [
               {
                  "primary" : null,
                  "id" : 5,
                  "reachability" : null,
                  "service_id" : 2
               }
            ],
            "trust_self_signed_certs" : true,
            "use_check" : false
         },
         {
```

I am now trying to extract all app_id values and need to run several CURL requests to

```
curl -X 'DELETE' \
  'https://website.com/api/v2/data/apps/conf/**<APP_ID>**' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Api-Token: TOKEN'
```

in order to delete these individal app_ids.

I hope you guys can quickly help me out here

thanks a lot, appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a simple question you should have tried it by yourself before asking here

- First import requests wich will allow you to call your api and json to convert the returned values to python objects:

```py
import requests
import json
```

- Then do the first request and get the json:

```py
response = requests.get('https://website.com/api/v2/data/apps/conf', headers={'accept': 'application/json', 'Api-Token': 'TOKEN'})
response = json.loads(response.text)
```

- You can then scrolle throught the json and send the request:

  ```py
  for conf in response['data']['conf']:
     app_id = conf['app_id']
     requests.delete(f'https://website.com/api/v2/data/apps/conf/{app_id}', headers={'accept': 'application/json', 'Api-Token': 'TOKEN'})
  ```

Comment: thanks @Scagg5, I tried this with some python modification but as it didnt work I didnt mean to post the code huddle.  indeed I needed a jumpstart. I used what you provided and I am adding additional use cases. thanks for your input on this one, that helped me.